# Issue in OL/LI tag in first time edit

Tags: editor, trix

I'm using the trix gem in my rails app. which has a front end in vuejs. When I enter text having OL and LI so in edit it displayed wrong format HTML even if I get the correct response from API

The initial text I enter is like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LZq4.png)

when I save and open in edit the same it shows me like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HIE1.png)

Details
Browser name and version: Chrome
Operating system: Ubuntu
*ruby-version: ' 2.7.0'
*rails-version: '6.0.0'